# Iterating over a zip() iterable

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have 2 lists of the same size, one is a list of vectors and the second is their respective tags:

```
l = [v1, v2,...]
tags = [True,False,...]
```

I want to make 2 lists, all the (vi,tag)'s which their tag are true, and it's compliment.
I'm trying to use the zip function for this like so:

```
true_grp = [x for x in zip(l,tags) if x[1] is True]
false_grp = [x for x in zip(l,tags) if x[1] is False]
```

Both lists turn up empty. I don't see the problem here, the 'x' should represent the tuple (vi,tag)

Comment: Your solution is working for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use [is](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is-not), you can check for boolean values directly. The `is` operator is for checking object identity, quoting the linked documentation:

> The operators is and is not test for object identity: x is y is true
>   if and only if x and y are the same object. Object identity is
>   determined using the id() function. x is not y yields the inverse
>   truth value

**Code**

```
l = list(range(5))
tags = [True, False, True, False, False]

true_grp = [x for x in zip(l,tags) if x[1]]
false_grp = [x for x in zip(l,tags) if not x[1]]

print(true_grp)
print(false_grp)
```

**Output**

```
[(0, True), (2, True)]
[(1, False), (3, False), (4, False)]
```

Comment: You have just reinvented `itertools.compress` (sort of)

Comment: @CodeHoarder see the linked documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution should work fine, but for clarity you can unpack items within a list comprehension. Note you *should* test for Boolean `x` via `if x`:

```
true_grp = [(value, flag) for value, flag in zip(l, tags) if flag]
false_grp = [(vale, flag) for value, flag in zip(l, tags) if not flag]
```

Since these lists are linked, much better is to use a dictionary to store "True" and "False" values. A [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is convenient:

```
from collections import defaultdict

grp = defaultdict(list)
for value, flag in zip(l, tags):
    grp[flag].append(value)
```

Then use `grp[0]` or `grp[False]` in place of `false_grp`; likewise, `grp[1]` or `grp[True]` in place of `true_grp`.

The one-pass dictionary-based solution also has the advantage of working for arbitrary iterables `l` and `tags`. If either of these are iterators, the list comprehension solution will not work for `false_grp`, as an iterable may only be traversed once.